# Using DELETE sql statement in node.js to delete a row in review table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sql-delete

I've attempted to do basically what the title says, though it hasn't deleted any rows after testing it in Postman. Here are the relevant lines of code.

deleteReview method in reviewController: This is in relation to the url used for my target link(?), http://localhost:8080/review/1, where the /1 at the end is the reviewId targetted for DELETE

```
function deleteReview(request, respond) {
    var review = new Review(request.params.reviewId);

    reviewsDB.deleteReview(reviewId, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            respond.json(error);
        } else {
            respond.json(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Attempted sql implementation:

```
deleteReview(review, callback){
    var sql = "DELETE FROM review WHERE reviewId = ?";

    db.query(sql, [review.getUserId(), review.getDatePosted(), review.getMessage(), review.getStarRating(), review.getReviewId()], callback);
}
```

Returned from Postman after trying to DELETE:

```
{
"fieldCount": 0,
"affectedRows": 0,
"insertId": 0,
"serverStatus": 2,
"warningCount": 0,
"message": "",
"protocol41": true,
"changedRows": 0
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What happens if you hard-code the value for `reviewId`?  Does the `DELETE` work that way?  If not, then you may need to add a `commit()` statement to actually "save" the changes to the DB.

Comment: @ravioli It does actually work with hard-coding. Not sure how I would do it without though.

Comment: Hmm, so the reviewId value is not being replaced properly when your SQL executes.  This line here: `[review.getUserId(), review.getDatePosted(), review.getMessage(), review.getStarRating(), review.getReviewId()]`, are these the parameters you're passing into the query?  If so, try removing all of them except for the `review.getReviewId()`.  Maybe your query is trying to replace the value with the `review.getUserId()` value, since it's the first one in the list.

Comment: @ravioli Nice that did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Woohoo! Glad it worked :)